# calling a function from inside another function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, function, loops

I need a little help. I'm trying to create a loop of three functions.
I created the first loop but I can not get to the first function after the
3rd one is done. 
I think the best solution is to call the first one inside the third one,
but I'm not sure this is the best way.
Anyway this is my code:

```
function LOADALL(event:MouseEvent):void{
if (ConditionC == "NotPlaying"){
    ConditionC = "Playing";
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(Sounds_Array[i]);
    var wav:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    wav.dataFormat = 'binary';
    wav.load(urlRequest);
    wav.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, playWav);
    }
}

function playWav(e:Event):void{
    var tts:WavSound = new WavSound(e.target.data as ByteArray);
    var channel:WavSoundChannel = tts.play();
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, completeHandler)
}

function completeHandler(e:Event):void{
    ConditionC = "NotPlaying";
trace ("hello");
LOADALL();
}
```

The error is in the 2nd from the end line ( LOADALL(); )

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `LOADALL` function without any arguments, when in fact it requires one argument: `event` - which is probably why you are getting an error. Since you are not using `event` in `LOADALL`, just pass `null`, ie:

```
LOADALL(null);
```

Comment: Great. Would you mind marking my answer as correct by clicking the tick?

Comment: You could also assign a default value to parameter function LOADALL(event:MouseEvent = null):void , that way you can call LOADALL like you did before.